# Reconfiguring hotwire/turbo for a Rails 7 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had built a twitter clone using an older version of Rails and the hotwire/turbo that went with it. I am now trying to re_build that project using the newer Rails, version 7, and find that in it the hotwire/turbo requests are processed in an html format instead of turbo format. I do not know how to implement this in my project such that the functionality for "liking" tweets continues to work. This is how that functionality worked previously:

The `likes_controller.rb` created the like and sent out its data in a turbo_stream format

```
  def create
    @like = current_user.likes.create(tweet: tweet)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.turbo_stream
    end
  end
```

The data from the controller was sent to `views/likes/create.turbo_stream.erb`

```
<%= turbo_stream.replace dom_id(@tweet) do %>
  <%= render partial: "tweets/tweet", locals: { tweet_presenter: TweetPresenter.new(@tweet) } %>
<% end %>
```

... from which it was dispatched to `presenters/tweet_presenter.rb` to be processed:

```
class TweetPresenter
  include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper

  def initialize(tweet)
    @tweet = tweet
  end

  attr_reader :tweet

  delegate :user, :body, :likes, to: :tweet
  delegate :username, :display_name, :avatar, to: :user

end
```

... and finally was delivered to `tweets/tweet.html.erb` wrapped in the following tag:

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(tweet_presenter.tweet) do %>
```

...inside of which it was displayed by this patch of code:

```
 <div>
        <%= link_to tweet_likes_path(tweet_presenter.tweet), data: { "turbo-method": "post" }, class: "text-decoration-none text-black likes" do %>
          <%= image_tag "heart.png", size: "20x20",class: "me-1" %>
          <span><%= tweet_presenter.likes.size %><span>
        <% end %>
      </div>
```

Any ideas how I can change this around so that the "likes" (I am only concerned about the count not the icon-change -that I'll get to later) continue to be registered and displayed, as they were doing before, without redoing the entire way the current likes model is set up?

Much obliged!

Comment: Issue solved! There were a couple of bugs in the soup that made it hard for me to isolate the problem. Once I got those out of the way, all I had to do to make this work was do away with the `respond to do |format|` block in the `likes_controller.rb` file, and then rename the `create.turbo_stream.erb` file in the `view/likes` folder to `create.html.erb`. All is working fine now.

Comment: it definitely still sends `TURBO_STREAM` requests. check the logs, check your browser console for any errors

Comment: Turbo is completely new in Rails 7. It replaces the functionality provided by Turbolinks (which evolved into Turbo Drive) and Rails UJS (RIP). Unless you're updating from another Rails 7 version thats what your app actually contained.